# method won't trigger when using requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have some issue with some requireJS setup. I posted a question before but the scope of the latest changed now.

I have some

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'tmpl': 'vendor/upload/tmpl.min'
    }
});
require({
    paths: {
        'videoupload': 'vendor/upload/jquery.ui.videoupload'
    }
}, ['js/main_video.js'], function (App) {
    App.initial_video_upload();
});
```

and finally in `main_video.js` :

```
define(['tmpl', 'videoupload'], function () {
        function initial_video_upload(tmpl, videoupload) {
            'use strict';
            $('#videoupload').videoupload({
                //...some code
            });
        }
        return{
            initial_video_upload: initial_video_upload
        }
    }
);
```

This code works perfectly if I don't use requireJS (loading classically each file). In fact, when this code is triggered, I keep on having a message `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tmpl'`, this method is defined in `tmpl.min.js`. And this method is invoked in `vendor/upload/jquery.ui.videoupload`, as so

```
$.widget('videoupload', {
//...
_renderVideo: function (video) {
    this._templateElement().tmpl({
        id: video.id,
        name: video.title
    }).appendTo(this._listElement()).find(
        this.options['delete-selector']
    );

    return this;
},
//...
```

How can I manage that ? (I had earlier an error time out message for this method tmpl, but it disappeared now, so I don't think this is it)

Comment: Have you checked the network monitor to see if `tmpl.min` is loading? It's unclear whether it's not loading at all or if your code is using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration object, the path is not the full path to the JS file BUT the path to the directory containing the JS file, so you may want to do something like this in the `main_video.js` file:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths:{
        'upload': 'vendor/upload'
    }

});
define(['upload/tmpl','upload/jquery_videoupload'],function(tmpl, videoupload) {
        function initial_video_upload(tmpl,videoupload){
            'use strict';
            $('#videoupload').videoupload({
                //...some code
            });
        }
        return{
            initial_video_upload: initial_video_upload
        }
    }
);
```

And in the main app:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths:{
        'js': 'path/to/your/js/folder'
    }

});
require(['js/main_video'], function(App) {
    App.initial_video_upload();
});
```

Comment: it didn't change anything. Weirder : I added the whole `tmpl.min` just before `initial_video_upload` and the `tmpl` is still not recognized

Comment: Can you remove all the "." and rename your modules as tmpl, initial_video_upload and main_video without ".min" and ".js"? See here for more information on naming: http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the questions code, so this:

```
define(['tmpl', 'videoupload'], function () {
```

should become this:

```
define(['tmpl', 'videoupload'], function (tmpl, videoupload) {
```

The first one doesn't expose loaded dependencies to local variables of closure function, so that's might be a problem, although it's not very clear if it's the only one, from the provided code.

I would also like to mention, that it's not a good thing to use multiple requre.js configs, if you're intended to use optimizer. The configs will be overwritten by the last one, so it's a good idea actually to have only one config for the whole project.

Like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'tmpl': 'vendor/upload/tmpl.min',
        'videoupload': 'vendor/upload/jquery.ui.videoupload'
    }
});
```